# MongoDB - Aggregation to find no. of entries date wise

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to implement a query in MongoDB to get the count of my records in the Database collection based on the column upload date. Its simply like **Find the max object Ids for each record and than group them date wise**

As I have multiple entries for one upload file which are segregated by an ObjectID. Hence, I have to group all the rows date wise but duplicate entries shall be considered for only with max Ids.

```
db.fs.files.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $add: [
          {
            $dayOfYear: "$uploadDate"
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              400,
              {
                $year: "$uploadDate"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      _id2: {
        $max: "$_id"
      },
      TotalUploads: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      f: {
        $min: "$uploadDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: "$f",
      TotalUploads: 1,
      object: "$_id2",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

---

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "filename": "22152_106046_6323041591916_D_04012209.jpg",
    "length": NumberLong(287171),
    "chunkSize": 261120,
    "uploadDate": ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.269Z"),
    "md5": "1223112",
    "metadata": {
      "_contentType": "image/jpg",
      "createdOn": ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.074Z"),
      "createdBy": "abc",
      "uploadStatus": "uploaded",
      "fileName": "22152_106046_6323041591916_D_04012209.jpg",
      "formType": "D",
      "elementIdAccountNoUin": "22152-106046-6323041591916",
      "contentType": "image/jpg",
      "formDate": ISODate("2209-01-04T05:00:00Z"),

    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have done the following code:

Comment: `      db.fs.files.aggregate([ 
       {
       $group: {_id: 
            {
             $add: 
                  [{
                    $dayOfYear: "$uploadDate"}, 
                   {$multiply: [400, {$year: "$uploadDate"}]}
                   ]},
                _id2: {$max: "$_id"}, TotalUploads: { $sum: 1 }, 
                f: {$min: "$uploadDate"}
           }
      }, 
      { 
         $sort: {_id: 1}
      }, 
      {
         $project: { date: "$f", TotalUploads: 1, object: "$_id2", _id: 0}
      } 
    ]); `

Comment: Please share collection ?

Comment: Please add the code to the original question, it's not readable as a comment.

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "filename" : "22152_106046_6323041591916_D_04012209.jpg", "length" : NumberLong(287171), "chunkSize" : 261120, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.269Z"), "md5" : "1223112", "metadata" : { "_contentType" : "image/jpg",, " "createdOn" : ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.074Z"), "createdBy" : "abc", "uploadStatus" : "uploaded", ", "fileName" : "22152_106046_6323041591916_D_04012209.jpg", "formType" : "D", "elementIdAccountNoUin" : "22152-106046-6323041591916", , "contentType" : "image/jpg", "formDate" : ISODate("2209-01-04T05:00:00Z"), } }

Comment: Its giving me the indenting errors continuously can you paste it to some of your editors? please

Comment: Can you post desired result? I dont understand why you need to multiply by 400 upload year...

Comment: Lets say I have an two uploads on 1st Jan with same file but the Object Id would be different. Similarly, I have 1 upload on 2nd jan. So, when I count the uploads date wise, it shall return "1" for 1st Jan [by grouping only the one with max Object ID i.e. Latest Upload] and "1" for 2nd Jan.

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I have an two uploads on 1st Jan with same file but the
>   Object Id would be different. Similarly, I have 1 upload on 2nd jan.
>   So, when I count the uploads date wise, it shall return "1" for 1st
>   Jan [by grouping only the one with max Object ID i.e. Latest Upload]
>   and "1" for 2nd Jan.

The following aggregation query will group by date (year/month/day) and find the maximum value of the `_id` for each grouping / date.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { $dateToString: { date: "$uploadDate", format: "%Y-%m-%d" } }, 
          maxId: { $max: "$_id" }
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: { uploadDate: "$_id", maxId: 1, fileCount: { $literal: 1 }, _id: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

For the input documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1 "filename" : "a.jpg", "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.269Z" }
{ "_id" : 2, "filename" : "b.jpg", "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-11-26T06:05:38.269Z" }
{ "_id" : 3, "filename" : "c.jpg", "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-11-30T06:05:38.269Z" }
```

The output:

```
{ "maxId" : 3, "fileCount" : 1, "uploadDate" : "2019-11-30" }
{ "maxId" : 2, "fileCount" : 1, "uploadDate" : "2019-11-26" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is a thing missing here that I need a counter of files ... like I have said before that if I have total 5 rows and 3 are uploaded on date 1 and 2 are uploaded on date two then it shall display the count of both dates as "1" because I will count only one for each date [The latest one only]. Here when I insert my count in your query than its considering all the rows not the maximum one for each row.

Comment: Yes, now you have the count by date.

Comment: Its showing count=2 for 26th November, it shall only count the latest entry on every date. Which means that count for both dates shall be 1